# Google Sheets count unique for all columns of a spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a spreadsheet with names and months. I'd like to do, for each month, the Sum for each name.

In O1 my formula is:

```
=query(A:M,"select A, sum(B), sum (C), sum(D) group by A offset 1")
```

The formula does the trick (here for the first 3 months) but I'm adding months after Month 12 so rapidly I'll have 50 months to count for.

Is there a way to add all the months instead of typing each time the column letter?

Second question, is there a way to change the name of the column label, instead of having sum Month 1, sum Month 2 etc

[image: Names&Months]

Thanks!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: There. Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veiYh1CMIfFPwBGQk4OwKmCLa7q08TugReVfAXtpIgI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY({A2:1000}, 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B1:1), 1, 2)&")")&"
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot (again!) player0